# What is the correct utf-8 encoding comment line for ruby?

Tags: ruby, unicode, encoding, utf-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ruby - UTF-8 file encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6444826/ruby-utf-8-file-encoding)

I'm using UTF-8 all the way and want to help the ruby interpreter to read my files.
Therefore I put `# encoding=utf-8` at the start of my ruby code like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# encoding=utf-8
```

But now and then, I see other variants:
`bundle gem NAME` inserts `# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-` (into NAME.gemspec). The gem [magic_encoding](https://github.com/m-ryan/magic_encoding) uses this line, too.

What is the recommended way?

- `# encoding = utf-8`
- `# encoding: utf-8`
- `# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer:

```
# encoding: utf-8
```

This is a complete answer:
[Ruby - UTF-8 file encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6444826/ruby-utf-8-file-encoding)

Comment: Thanks. Because of the given link, I marked this as answer.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like a fairly relaxed specification for what's acceptable. I've always used:

```
# encoding: UTF-8
```

Also acceptable is `coding`. I can't find a reference on the variants allowed, but so long as your file is being interpreted correctly it should be fine. Check the `__ENCODING__` value to be sure it's being picked up.

Comment: Thanks. I tried all variants - and all work.

Answer (score 3):

Python behaves the same way, and the answer to [this Python question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728891/correct-way-to-define-python-source-code-encoding) suggests there is no real recommendation, just choose what works for your editor: for Emacs, use the `# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-`; for VIM use `# vim:fileencoding=<encoding-name>`.

Comment: It's a good advice to stick to your editor's modelines. Thanks!